# German for "USP"?

Tags: idiom

I'm wondering if there's any German approximation of "Unique Selling Point"?

I'm trying to say that BMW's USP is their cars' sporty driving dynamics.

Comment: English Wikipedia -> Unique selling point -> choose Deutsch on the left panel -> "Alleinstellungsmerkmal"

Comment: unique selling proposition = Alleinstellungsmerkmal, einzigartiger Wettbewerbsvorteil, einzigartiges Verkaufsversprechen

Answer (score 1):

When I founded my company, and during my studies at University of Applied Sciences I learned that USP is the abbreviation for ”*Unique Selling **Proposition***“. I have never heard ”*Unique Selling **Point***“ before. (Which does not mean that the latter is wrong. It just seems to be rarely used, at least in Austria.)

In German economics language those terms are used as synonyms:

> USP (with English pronunciation [juːɛspʰiː])
>   USP (with German pronunciation [uːɛspeː])
>   Alleinstellungsmerkmal

Sometimes this is used in German sentences (when talking about economics among experts):

> unique selling proposition